# Can App create by Android Studio be submitted to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, android-studio

Under iOS, one can't use beta Xcode to create submitted for AppStore.  Can Android Studio be used to develop app submitted for Play Store?

Comment: That's why you have Android Studio. To create app and put to the store.

Comment: The answer to any question, "I can't do X in iOS, can I do it in Android?" is always yes.

Comment: You can install the DroidLane plugin to submit automatically.
https://github.com/Jintin/DroidLane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

submitting an app to google play store requires you to upload an signed .apk file.

> Can Android Studio be used to develop app submitted for Play Store?

Yes
But you need to export a signed apk file, then login to google play account, and upload it

Comment: You can also install the DroidLane plugin to submit by Android Studio. https://github.com/Jintin/DroidLane

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it's possible, I've done it myself, you'll generate a .apk with AS and it's definitely usable on Google Play Store !

[Here are all the steps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html) to get your app ready for the Google Play Store; [Here is the way](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-android-studio) to sign your apk using Android Studio.

I hope this answer helps =)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. At the end do Build > Generate signed APK and fill out the relevant information (Google around if you get lost). Then, you get a Google Play Developer account for $25 (£18) and upload your apps.